# P and br tag is not displayed in Wordpress Database

Tags: html, wordpress

I have installed tinymce-advanced plugin and click **Stop removing the p and br tags when saving and show them in HTML editor** option in plugin setting and save it.I have created a post and publish it. But, When I have fired query on WordPress Database. It not showing me that p and br tag.Please help me into this?

Comment: Once you can inspect element in console showing tag or not. then check your editor in text mode(not visual mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's (a pared-down version of) what I use to custom-configure TinyMCE:

```
function custom_tinymce_config( $init ) {
    // Don't remove line breaks
   $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false; 
   // Convert newline characters to BR tags
   $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true; 
   // Do not remove redundant BR tags
   $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;

    // Pass $init back to WordPress
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'custom_tinymce_config');
```

Would you please add above code in your current theme `functions.php`?

Play around with the [TinyMCE configuration parameters](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/), and find the one that you need to change.